# Cannot find appcfg.py or dev_appserver.py?

Tags: python, google-app-engine, macos, bash

My computer says...

"-bash: appcfg.py: command not found"

What is wrong?

I can run my application using google-app-engine-launcher and I have python pre-installed.

I am trying to upload my app using "appcfg.py update *myapp*"

I am new to Mac development.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

In App Engine launcher there is a menu option called "Make Symlinks..." that adds symlinks for the various App Engine utility commands, like appcfg.py.

Comment: +1 Had to do this again after the App Engine Launcher updated itself.

Comment: It would be trivial for the update process to redo the deleted symlinks, and save the unnecessary panic, search and then the fix. Come on Google.

Answer (score 4):

This is how my path dir looks like: Home/Brice/google_projects/google_appengine

I store both the **google_appengine** and my **google_apps** in my **google_projects** folder

In terminal: (While in my google_projects folder)

upload to localhost:

```
google_appengine/dev_appserver.py appname
```

upload to GAE:

```
google_appengine/appcfg.py update appname
```

and replace appname with the name of your app folder

Hope that helps!

Answer (score 3):

If someone (like me) comes across this more recently due to `appcfg.py` and `dev_appserver.py` still appearing frequently in the documentation:

> ## 0.9.68 (2015/07/08)
>
> [...]
>
> - The standalone App Engine SDKs are no longer distributed through the Cloud
>     SDK.
>
>   - App Engine functionality can still be used through the
>       `gcloud preview app` command group.
>   - [...]
>   - If you need to use appcfg or dev_appserver directly, these are still
>       available in the App Engine SDK downloads that can be found here:
>       https://cloud.google.com/appengine/downloads

(from `google-cloud-sdk/RELEASE_NOTES`)

Answer (score 1):

Try: `./appcfg.py`

Current dir is usually not part of path.

Answer (score 1):

If is not in a directory specified in the PATH environment variable and marked executable it wont execute by calling its plain name.

when in doubt the following should always work:

```
python /path/to/appcfg.py <your arguments>
```

Answer (score 1):

Because the top-voted and accepted answer doesn't explain this, and not everyone will read the comments on it, here's what to do:

- Ensure you've installed  Google App Engine SDK/Launcher from https://cloud.google.com/appengine/downloads?csw=1
- Within it, select the option to "Make Symlinks...". "Make Command Symlinks?" may pop up in a dialog when you open it for the first time or after it's updated itself.
- You'll have to do this each time it updates itself or it'll stop working. This is often what's gone wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Using command line there are two options
1. make the two files executable and create symbolic links for them

```
# chmod +x path/to/google_appengine/dev_appserver.py
# ln -s /path/to/google_appengine/dev_appserver.py /bin
# chmod +x path/to/google_appengine/appcfg.py
# ln -s /path/to/google_appengine/appcfg.py /bin
```

2. export PATH and PYTHONPATH variables. To do this add following lines in `.bashrc` file

```
export PATH=$PATH:/path/to/google_appengine/
export PYTHONPATH="$PYTHONPATH:/path/to/google_appengine:/path/to/google_appengine/‌​lib/:/path/to/google_appengine/lib/yaml/"
```