# command not found error creating Upload Script for mobile app with an App Engine backend

Tags: android, bash, shell, google-app-engine

So I have been following the tutorial at this website: https://cloud.google.com/developers/articles/how-to-build-mobile-app-with-app-engine-backend-tutorial

I got through the first part, but I am stuck at the Create an Upload Script part. I am doing this through eclipse so when I try and run the command through the terminal, I get an error:
./upload_data.sh: line 2: appcfg.cmd: command not found

The contents of my upload_data.sh file are listed on the tutorial site.

as listed on the site. I have tried appcfg.sh and appcfg.sh as well but they both don't work. I cannot get the places.csv info onto my server so I cannot proceed.
Any help or insight would be great. Thanks

Comment: Have a look at this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5187602/cannot-find-appcfg-py-or-dev-appserver-py

Comment: I get this error now:./upload_data.sh <places.csv> Place
09:32 PM Uploading data records.
kind argument required unless --dump, --restore or --create_config specified

Comment: Nvm I got it to work.

Comment: @user3129120, So, how did you got it work? You should post your solution.

Comment: I wasn't running the command correctly and the arguments weren't correctly added.