# With Google App Engine, why do I now get "command not found" when running the appcfg.py command on my local machine?

Tags: google-app-engine

This started after I ran the latest gcloud update:

```
gcloud components update
```

I used to be able to deploy my app something like this:

```
appcfg.py update app.yaml
```

Now I get:

```
appcfg.py: command not found
```

Is there a new `gcloud` command for deploying App Engine apps?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`gcloud app deploy` is the preferred way when using `gcloud`. If you download the stand alone Google App Engine SDK, then you will have `appcfg.py` available.

https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/app/deploy

Comment: I saw that page at some point in my troubleshooting. It was this note at the bottom that made me doubt that this was now the preferred approach to deploying App Engine apps: **This command is currently in BETA and may change without notice.**

Comment: That is correct, but that is also why you are seeing the problems you reported here. Don't be surprised if they move `appcfg.py` again in the future. If you use `gcloud`, use `gcloud preview app deploy`, if not download the [standalone sdk](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/downloads?hl=en) and use `appcfg.py` directly. I use both and the `gcloud` way seems to be a moving target at the moment.

Comment: You no longer need the `preview` part - just `gcloud app deploy` :)

Comment: Finally! It's been a long time coming. Maybe now I won't have to update my app every other week to keep up with the refactoring of gcloud.

Answer (score 10):

It appears the most recent version of gcloud dropped `appcfg.py` from the `bin` directory.

```
$ ls ~/google-cloud-sdk/bin/
bootstrapping  bq  dev_appserver.py  gcloud  git-credential-gcloud.sh  gsutil
```

I found the `appcfg.py` script under the `platform` directory:

```
$ ls ~/google-cloud-sdk/platform/google_appengine
api_server.py           dev_appserver.py      LICENSE               RELEASE_NOTES
appcfg.py ...
```

By linking it back to the `bin` directory, I was able to restore the command.

```
ln -sv ~/google-cloud-sdk/platform/google_appengine/appcfg.py ~/google-cloud-sdk/bin/
```

Credit to [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32219647/1093087) for helping me to figure this out.

Comment: There is no longer a google_appengine folder in platform/

Comment: yes there is, you just need to install the App Engine components.
run the following to see what components you have installed:
"gcloud components list" run the following to install AppEngine "gcloud components install app-engine-python"

Comment: Exactly what i was looking for:

ln -sv ~/google-cloud-sdk/platform/google_appengine/appcfg.py ~/google-cloud-sdk/bin/

Answer (score 1):

in my case, i needed to run the following:

```
sudo ln -sv /usr/local/google-cloud-sdk/platform/google_appengine/appcfg.py /usr/local/google-cloud-sdk/bin/
```

Answer (score 0):

using `gcloud app deploy --project project-appengine-id`
You'll need to have a billing account

Answer (score 0):

As the standalone Google App Engine SDK is no longer available, if you still need access to appcfg.py (for instance, if you are trying to set up Eclipse for an App Engine Standard project that uses Python 2 according to [these instructions](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/tools/setting-up-eclipse)), I have found that one way to get it is to just install an older version of the Cloud SDK.

Specifically, appcfg.py was apparently removed in Cloud SDK version 344.0.0 when the Python SDK was updated to version 1.9.93, so you can run:

```
gcloud components install app-engine-python
gcloud components update --version 343.0.0
```

and this will give you the most recent version of the app-engine-python component that still had that file.