# Google App Engine deploy with Django module after gcloud update?

Tags: django, google-app-engine, gcloud, google-app-engine-python

We are deploying to GAE using Django 1.7 (we are sending it as a symlinked module of our `virtualenv`). Everything was fine up until the latest update of the `gcloud` tools.

Now when we execute `$ gcloud preview app deploy app.yaml` we get:

```
Updating module [default]...failed.

ERROR: (gcloud.preview.app.deploy) Error Response: [400] Invalid 
JSON payload received. Unknown name "datata_devops/local/libs/django
/contrib/formtools/locale/hr/_lc_messages/django.mo" at 
'version.deployment.files[2368]': Repeated map key: 'datata_devops/local
/libs/django/contrib/formtools/locale/hr/LC_MESSAGES/django.mo' is 
already set.
```

We are guessing this has to do with the fact that we upload our own version of Django, but we have no idea on how to solve this. We have tried using a computer with an older version of the `gcloud` tools, but we are getting the `Too many files (limit is 10,000)` error.

Any hints on how to overcome this issue with the latest `gcloud`? Thanks!

Comment: You should open this up on the Issue Tracker[1]. Make sure you include the steps to reproduce (ie link the exact vserion of Django, the structure you are using ...).[1]https://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/issues/entry

Comment: The [Google Cloud SDK](https://code.google.com/p/google-cloud-sdk/issues/list) issue tracker would be more appropriate here, but Ryan's suggestion is a good one.

Comment: Thanks to both. I'll report the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Alternate approaches to `gcloud preview app deploy`:

- check this @klenwell's answer to this Q&A for the new location of
  `appcfg.py` in the Google Cloud SDK:
  [With Google App Engine, why do I now get "command not found" when running the appcfg.py command on my local machine?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33202667/with-google-app-engine-why-do-i-now-get-command-not-found-when-running-the-ap/33217281#33217281)
- use the [GAE SDK](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/downloads#Google_App_Engine_SDK_for_Python)'s `appcfg.py` to update your app.

Comment: Thank you. Deploying with `appcfg.py` worked. I'll report the erroneous behavior in the [Google Cloud SDK](https://code.google.com/p/google-cloud-sdk/issues/list) as Zachary suggested.

I won't mark this a resolved because this is a workaround a pending issue. I'll leave it open in case someone has an answer directly to the mentioned issue.