# Error Response: [13] An internal error occurred, when deploying project on Google Cloud SDK

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform

I have been trying to deploy my project on Google Cloud SDK since yesterday and have been getting the same error over and over.

My app.yaml file looks like:

```
runtime: python27
api_version: 1
threadsafe: yes

- url: /
  static_files: bin/index.html 
  upload: bin/index.html

- url: /assets
  static_dir: bin/assets 

- url: /src
  static_dir: bin/src

- url: /vendor
  static_dir: bin/vendor

- url: /templates-app.js
  static_files: static/templates-app.js 
  upload: static/templates-app.js

- url: /templates-common.js
  static_files: static/templates-common.js 
  upload: static/templates-common.js

- url: .*
  script: main.app
```

I use this command to deploy:

> gcloud preview app deploy app.yaml --version 1 --promote --force

And I get this error:

```
Beginning deployment...
Copying files to Google Cloud Storage...
Synchronizing files to [gs://staging.myapp.appspot.com/].
Updating module [default]...failed.
ERROR: (gcloud.preview.app.deploy) Error Response: [13] An internal error occurred.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It ended up being the `reportlab` python library in the `lib` folder.

I found inserting it as a zip file rather than a normal folder worked.

```
import sys
sys.path.insert(0, 'reportlab.zip')

import reportlab
...
```

I have no idea why it wouldn't work. But I remember seeing something about a file limit when uploading projects with app-engine. Deploying 1 zip file is better than 181 files that make up `reportlab`.

Comment: Getting the same error right now. No details beyond error 13 seems like something else is broken. I have a lot of files, but am not above any limit, unless the limits changed recently.

Comment: I got the error a few times. Reducing file count helped every time for me.

Answer (score 3):

I got the same error today `Error Response: [13] An internal error occurred`.

In my case, the issue was because I have a folder that has over `1000 files`. Once I moved some of these files elsewhere, the internal error message disappeared!

I tried `1000 files` in one folder, and it worked, then, I added one file `(1001 files total)` in the same folder, and the same internal error came back. It seems that it is kind of a limit that google app engine has `1000 files per folder`.

Comment: Good to know what the max file limit is

Answer (score 0):

I notice you don't have your app name in the `app.yaml` file and you also don't specify it in the upload cmd. I'd suggest making a habit in providing as much as the info as possible in the `app.yaml` to minimize the chances of human error. You can also specify the version in the `app.yaml` as well. This habit will help when you'll get to multi-modules apps, where such info is mandatory. See examples in the [modules config doc](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/modules/#Python_Configuration).

From a different prospective, I saw several reports in which `gcloud preview app deploy` tripped, you can always try alternate approaches to rule out such cases, see my answer to this Q&A: [Google App Engine deploy with Django module after gcloud update?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33231486/google-app-engine-deploy-with-django-module-after-gcloud-update/33249395#33249395)

Comment: I have found the opposite, that commands like `gcloud preview app deploy ...` tend to complain about `application` and `version` being in the app.yaml. So these days I mostly add those to the command line (--project xxx --version yyy) when deploying, except when running local servers with the GoogleAppEngineLauncher.