# GAE "min_pending_latency" error in app.yaml

Tags: google-app-engine, configuration

I just completed a `gcloud components update` on my local machine and got several new errors when deploying my application. I was able to fix most of these new errors with a few minutes of troubleshooting (I understand that the `gcloud preview app` command is still 'preview', so I expect some changes here.)

I am now getting an error (bug?) that I can't seem to fix.

```
ERROR: (gcloud.preview.app.deploy) Error Response: [400]
version.automatic_scaling.min_pending_latency (nanos: 300000000),
must be in the range [0.010000s,15.000000s].
```

So, correct me if I'm wrong, but I'm pretty sure 300000000 nanos falls in the acceptable range as defined in the error.

These are the relevant sections of my app.yaml

```
module: api
runtime: php55
api_version: 1
threadsafe: true

instance_class: F2
automatic_scaling:
  min_idle_instances: automatic
  max_idle_instances: automatic
  min_pending_latency: 300ms
  max_pending_latency: 1s
```

Comment: I did manage to get this version to deploy using the `automatic` value for the `min_pending_latency` property as a temporary workaround.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just tried the `300ms` config on my app, but updating using the GAE SDK's `appcfg.py` - no issue, which supports your suspicion of a bug in the `gcloud preview` CLI. You might want to file an issue with the [Google Cloud SDK Issue Tracker](https://code.google.com/p/google-cloud-sdk/issues/list).

As a workaround you could either:

- check this @klenwell's answer to this Q&A for the new location of
  `appcfg.py` in the Google Cloud SDK:
  [With Google App Engine, why do I now get "command not found" when running the appcfg.py command on my local machine?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33202667/with-google-app-engine-why-do-i-now-get-command-not-found-when-running-the-ap/33217281#33217281)
- use the GAE SDK's `appcfg.py` to update your app.

Comment: Interesting that appcfg.py doesn't suffer from the same issues. I've submitted an issue at https://code.google.com/p/google-cloud-sdk/issues/detail?id=327

Comment: `appcfg.py` has been around for several years, it is more mature.